# Is it possible to manage Server Manager Properties through PowerShell DSC?

Tags: windows, dsc

For example:

1. Server Manager → Manage → Server Manager Properties "Do not Start manager automatically at logon"
2. Server Manager → Local Server → IE Enhanced Security Configuration → Off

Comment: For the first one set the following Registry DWORD: `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ServerManager\DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon` to 1

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - please, arrange as an answer. Even if it does not answer in full, it still merits a +1.

Answer (score 1):

To change the `Do not Start manager automatically at logon` setting, you can set a registry value (DWORD):

```
Key: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ServerManager

Value: DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon
```

a value of 1, disabled the startup after logon.

I just checked my old Server-Install scripts and found this for IE Enhanced Security Configuration:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" -Name “IsInstalled” -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" -Name “IsInstalled” -Value 0
```

you need to translate it into DSC syntax.